# 「画像処理をする際、グレースケール変換が必要なケース」としては、どういう処理が挙げられるでしょうか？

Tags: 画像

**下記の意味は、「グレースケール」変換後「カラー」へ再変換すれば高速になるのではなく、「カラー」が不要な処理は色情報を削除した方が良い、ということでしょうか？**

> 画像処理では、計算処理を効率よく行うために、カラー画像よりグレースケール画像を多く用います

[link](http://www.igunoss.co.jp/imageproc/imageproc1-3.html)

---

**「画像処理でグレースケール変換するケース」としては、例えばどんな処理があるでしょうか？**

・2値化？
・エッジ検出？

---

**基本的に「グレースケール」変換した内容は「カラー」へ戻さない、という認識で合っているでしょうか？**
・結果を「カラー」で受け取りたい処理は、「グレースケール」変換しない方が良い？

Comment: Q1に関しては具体的なコードを提示してもらえませんか？Q2,3はcanvasに限った話ではないでしょうし、質問タイトルからも離れた内容かと思いますから、別の質問にされた方がよろしいかと。

Comment: 勘違いに気が付いたので、質問内容を修正しました。当初とニュアンスが異なっているのは意図的です。また、「具体的なコードを提示してもらえませんか？」については、コード以前の問題として、基本的な考え方を知りたかったため、提示していません

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 下記の意味は、「グレースケール」変換後「カラー」へ再変換すれば高速になるのではなく、「カラー」が不要な処理は色情報を削除した方が良い、ということでしょうか？

主に下記理由によります：

- 多くの画像処理アルゴリズムは単一チャネル（グレースケール）画像のみを対象とする
- 人間の視覚特性として色差成分よりも、輝度成分に対して強い感度を持っている
- 計算量削減・作業メモリ削減のために、扱うデータが3チャネルよりも1チャネルの方が好ましい

なお、単一チャネルのグレイスケール画像のみから、カラー画像（3チャネル画像）を復元することは **原理的に不可能** です。一般にグレイスケール画像という場合、カラー画像から「色差」という情報を削ぎ落とし、主成分である「輝度」情報のみに要約したものを指します。

> 「画像処理でグレースケール変換するケース」としては、例えばどんな処理があるでしょうか？

色情報を利用する必要が無く、空間情報（オブジェクト形状など）に着目するアルゴリズムでは、グレースケール変換を行います。

> 基本的に「グレースケール」変換した内容は「カラー」へ戻さない、という認識で合っているでしょうか？
>   結果を「カラー」で受け取りたい処理は、「グレースケール」変換しない方が良い？

（狭義の解釈をする限り、）"戻さない" ではなく戻すことが **出来ません**。

あなたの言う「グレースケール変換」が、3チャネルカラー画像から1チャネルの輝度プレーン＋2チャネルの色差プレーンへの変換（いわゆるRGB→YUV変換）を意味しているならば、輝度プレーン処理結果に従って色差プレーンにも画像処理を適用／色差プレーンはそのままに、その後RGB色空間に逆変換することは良くあります。

Comment: 内容難しかったのですが、下記のような解釈で合っているでしょうか？　「一般的なグレイスケール画像は単一チャネルなのでカラー復元不可」。「RGB→YUV変換はグレイスケール画像とは呼ばないけれども、変換後のカラー復元可」。つまり、「見た目がグレーかどうかで判断するのではなく、1チャネルの輝度プレーンしか持たない画像が狭義のグレイスケール画像」ということでしょうか？

Comment: コメント鉤括弧「」は、3点ともYESです。RGB→YUV変換は色の表現方法を変更しているだけですから、数式上は情報の欠落はおきません。ただしコンピュータで数値を扱う都合上、RGB→YUV→RGB変換過程において若干の演算誤差や丸めがは生じてしまいます。

Comment: 基本的なことが分かっていなかったため、検索していくとアレ？ となることが多かったのですが、おかげで疑問が解決しました。「RGB→YUV→RGB変換」については、可逆だけれども100%可逆ではないわけですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

一応自分も専門家ではないので間違っている部分があるかもしれませんので、すべて鵜呑みにはしないでください。

色については[もう一つの質問をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29041/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%98%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)。また表現法間の変換は（基本同じ色の範囲を扱っていれば）可逆なので、グレースケール（＋色度）からRGB全色戻すことは可能です。

---

引用は多分エッジ検出とか関連なので色は捨てるという意味だと思いますが、現実的に何度も調整する場合1度グレーにして、何度か処理してカラーに戻したほうが早い場合は十分あると思います。

---

人間は明るさに敏感なので、人が気になる部分（エッジなど）を見つける場合はグレースケールで処理するのが多いと思います、色情報にあまり特長見えませんし…（参照：[YUV画像の各値をそれぞれ示したもの](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Barn-yuv.png)）。ただ必要というわけではなく、うまくRGBすべて使うアルゴリズムはあるでしょうが、処理速度に結果が見合うかと言われるとグレースケールで良いことが大半だと思います。またRGBのうち1つを使うのでは画像によっては全く特徴が現れないので（例えばほぼ青い画像にR要素のみを使う）どんな画像にも同じ様な結果を求めるのであれば、RGBすべてを使うのでなければグレースケールへの変換は必須と言えます。
質問であげられた例のほかに以下（分類があいまいですが）でもグレースケールのみを使うことは考えられると思います（またそこから得た情報を色度にも反映）。

1. ノイズ検出・除去

   1. アンチエイリアス
   2. ブロック検出：除去
   3. 半透明ロゴの除去
2. 周期性検出（フーリエ変換）
3. モーション検出・補間（主に動画）
4. シーン変化検出（動画）

Comment: 「グレースケール変換」は見た目をグレー化するためだけに使用するものだとばかり最初思っていたのですが、使用場面は色々あるのですね。参考になりました

Comment: yohjoさんが答えられた様に、多くのアルゴリズムは1チャンネルしか扱えないので、必然的にグレースケールにしているという感じでは無いでしょうか。で、変換方法はre9さのもう一つの質問にある理由で選ばれているのだともいます