# グレースケール変換の方法は、どうして複数存在するのでしょうか？

Tags: 画像

**NTSC 係数を使用している例が多いようにも思うのですが、この方法のメリットとしてどんな点が挙げられるでしょうか？**

**YCbCr変換は、上記とは全く関係ない？**
・「YCbCr」と「YCrCb」は同じ意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

前提：人間が知覚できる「色」を数値表現するため、[色空間(color space)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%89%B2%E7%A9%BA%E9%96%93)とよばれる3次元の空間を定義します。ある色を3次元空間における点にマッピングすることで、任意の色は "3個の値の組" として記述できます。

> グレースケール変換の方法は、どうして複数存在するのでしょうか？

PC業界で一般によく知られたRGB色空間や、TV業界で用いられるYUV色空間など、色空間には唯一絶対という物が存在しません。厳密には"RGB色空間"は総称にすぎず、"Adobe RGB"や"sRGB"など異なる色空間が定義されています。同様に"YUV色空間"についても、厳密には"NTSC YIQ"や"BT.601"(SDTV), "BT.709"(HDTV), "BT.2020"(4K/8K)などテレビ放送の規格に合わせて異なる色空間が定義されています。

グレイスケール変換は「RGB色空間からYUV色空間への変換（のY成分だけに着目）」に相当しますが、変換元／変換先の色空間の組み合わせに応じて複数の変換式が存在します。

> NTSC 係数を使用している例が多いようにも思うのですが、この方法のメリットとしてどんな点が挙げられるでしょうか？

「NTSCにより規格化された標準的な仕様である」という点を除けばメリットありません。NTSCは主に北米＋日本で採用されている仕様ですが、世界的にはPAL（主に欧州）、SECAM（ロシア＋一部アフリカ）と少なくとも3種類のメジャーな仕様が存在します。NTSCとPAL/SECAMで色空間は微妙に異なっていますが、色空間変換に関してはNTSCだから優れた点というのは特に存在しません。

> YCbCr変換は、上記とは全く関係ない？

YCbCrと表記した場合、ITU-R BT.601で定義される色空間を指すことが多いです。BT.601で定義される係数はNTSCと同一です。

> 「YCbCr」と「YCrCb」は同じ意味でしょうか？

色空間としては同じですが、データの順序（メモリ格納順や信号送出順など）が異なることを表現しています。

Comment: "YUV色空間"を"RGB色空間"に例えた話が分かりやすかったです。言われてみれば確かに"RGB色空間"も一つではないですね。「色空間には唯一絶対という物が存在しません」という説明もなるほどと思いました。「NTSC」や「YCbCr」についての説明も、大変参考になりました

Comment: 参考までに：工学用途以外ではあまり目にしませんが、あらゆる色を正値で表現できる「CIE XYZ 表色系(JIS Z8701)」という国際的に統一された色空間も存在します。他の色空間はこのCIE XYZを使って厳密に定義されていたりします。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございました。別件ですが、「RGBをLabへ変換する際、一旦XYZへ変換しているコードがあり何故だろう？」と疑問に思っていたのですが、上記コメントで疑問が解決しました。「CIE XYZ」とはそういう位置付けの色空間なのですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 2):

一応自分も専門家ではないので間違っている部分があるかもしれませんので、すべて鵜呑みにはしないでください。

[もう一つのグレースケールに関する質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28973/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B-%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%8C%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81%E3%81%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%8C%E6%8C%99%E3%81%92%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)とも関連していますが、YUV/YIQ/YCbCr/YPbPr系統の表現法はパソコンでよく使われるRGBとは違い、色を表すのに「輝度＝グレースケール(Y)」と「色度（UV）」の二つからなります。Yはすべてで共通です。UVは二次元空間で色を示しますが、この空間にどの範囲の色を、どう配置し、どの角度でx,y座標を引くかで微妙に名前と変換時の係数が変わってきます。
それでYUVはヨーロッパなどで使われていたPAL形式での座標を、YIQは北アメリカや日本で使われていたNTSC形式の座標を示し、IQはUVを33度回転したものでした。今では厳密にはYUVではないものも、YIQよりはYUVにそれらの色度座標が近いためこの形式すべてひっくるめてYUVとよく言われます（実際の係数はBT.601やBT.709という名前/規格で区別されているみたいです）。

また人間の目はすべての色を均等には感知しません。YUV(PAL)では色の境に座標を置いたため両方の軸が同じ重要度を持ちますが、YIQ(NTSC)ではI軸がオレンジ・青、Q軸が紫・緑に乗っているので、敏感なI情報に帯域を多く割り当てることにより同じ情報量で人にとってはより鮮やかな映像が見せれます（ちなみに今時のAVCコーデックでも同じことが行われています）。
色をパソコン上で扱う場合多くはRGBを使います。これは画面が「人にとっての三原色」である赤緑青を使っているからだと思います。しかし前に書いたように、人は同じ強さの赤と緑を同じ明るさとは見ないので、RGB-YUV間で変換する場合輝度（Y)はRGBから均等にとりません。
軸の取り方は英語Wikipediaの画像を見比べるとわかりやすいかと思います（[YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:YUV_UV_plane.svg),[YIQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:YIQ_IQ_plane.svg)）。
またここら辺は画像処理でRGBから1度変換される理由にも通じていて、RGBを直接割ったりすと色合いがゆがみますが、YIQではYを割ればすべての色が均等に変わります。

まとめとしてよくNTSC方式を見る理由ですが、RGBから一定の係数で各値を使うのは人の目が色ごとの感度が違うからです。ただその理由でグレースケールのみ使うのであればPAL方式でも同じなので単純に日本やアメリカの情報を見ているからというのが一番大きいと思います。
なんにしろ、最近のAVCなどで使われるYUVはNTSCでもPALでもないので、RGB（実はRGBでもsRGBやAdobeRGBなど複数ある）以外を使う場合はデータに使われている色空間はしっかり確認したほうが良いと思います。

---

YCbCrとYCrCbは同じ情報だと思いますが順序が違うのは保存順が違うからとかではないでしょうか。

Comment: ＞最近のAVCなどで使われるYUVはNTSCでもPALでもない。情報ありがとうございました。「使われている色空間の確認」は大事だなと思いました

Comment: MPEG-2 Video以降（たしか）の映像コーデックでは、メタ情報として色空間を埋め込めるようになっています。そのためH.264/AVCでもNTSCやPALを使うことも出来ます。ただ、このメタ情報まで考慮して表示してくれるプレイヤでないと、色合いが微妙にズレてしまいますね。

Comment: 普段使用している動画プレイヤーで確認してみましたが、「NTSC ／ PAL」選択は出来ませんでした。しかし、一眼カメラの映像出力方式を確認したら「NTSC ／ PAL」を選択できるようになっていたのでびっくりしました(初めて気が付きました)

Comment: アナログ入出力ができるのであれば、わざとPALにしてみると面白いかもしれません（色の表現以外も本当は違うのですが、雰囲気はわかると思います）。アナログ時代のPAL/NTSC選択ミスは明らかにおかしいので気付くのですが、最近のBT.601とBT.709などの差は数値見ないとわからなくて、メタデータがないものを拾ったりすると悲しくなりますね（笑